# How to Push otherviewcontroller on uibutton click event in uitabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

this is my `UITabBarController` code
in `appdelegate.m` file

```
UITabBarController *tbController =(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tbAppearence = [UITabBar appearance];
```

now,i have three `button` in one of the `UITabBarController` view,when i click one of the `button` the screen will redirect to other view but it can't.

This is my button action code
In UserInfoViewController.m file

```
- (IBAction)AskQuestionButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Ask Button pressed");
    AskQuestion *AskQuestionObject = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AskQuestionID"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:AskQuestionObject animated:YES];    
}
```

plz help me i'm new in ios.

Comment: Check `UIVC` identifier.

Comment: its same ''AskQuestionID'',but nothing happen.

Comment: Then add your tab bar code. I mean when you add Vc's in tab bar.

Comment: cant't understand you. plz be specific because i'm new in ios development field.

Comment: check this sample and check your sample is according to this or not, because this is working code. It helps you alot. [sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396392/add-a-tab-bar-controller-programmatically-to-current-app-flow)

Comment: thanks but its not working..

Comment: thats why i am saying add your code in your question.

Comment: thats the only code..

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your `UIViewcontroller` in your tabBar like this below code.

Here's a sample of my `UITabBarController` subclass:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIViewController *view1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *view2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *view3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:view1];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:view2];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:view3];

    [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];
    //can't set this until after its added to the tab bar
    view1.tabBarItem = 
      [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view1" 
                                    image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view1"] 
                                      tag:1];
    view2.tabBarItem = 
      [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view2" 
                                    image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view3"] 
                                      tag:2];
    view3.tabBarItem = 
      [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view3" 
                                    image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view3"] 
                                      tag:3];      
}
```

Comment: UIViewController *view1 = [[AskQuestion alloc] init];
     NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [tabViewControllers addObject:view1];
     [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];
    view1.tabBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view1"
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view1"]
                                    tag:1];
this error in [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];  No visible @interface for 'UserInfoViewController' declares the selector 'setViewControllers:'